# Ist possible to make a hybrid jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs, slider, coda

I want to make a jQuery script with tabs like the coda slider but inside the content div i want to put a slider to scroll from the left to the right. Because I want to make a product listing and the tabs will be the product  types and the content the product but i want to make the product list scollable because I have 100 products and these 100 doesn't fit in the single content div or at leas it doesn't look good. So can anyone help me how to make a script With tabs and scrollable content div?

Thx guys

Comment: How far have you got by now? Show us some code please.

Answer (score 0):

Search for [jQuery's slide menu](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/slide-menu)

Comment: Ohh no... I want something different.. A want to put this slider: o something similar: [link](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/1.1.1/) aaand put a slider in the bottom of every content page like this: [link](http://www.mopstudio.jp/mopSlider2demo.html)

Comment: @IstvánNagy: so looking for this http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/